# How to reset text strikethough when an item is removed from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The stikethough and text color is NOT updated (reset) even though the item is removed from the list. Thus, when I add new item, there is unexpected stikethough on text and text color. I tried to fix this issue by adding "paint.setFlag(holder.itemName.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) in onBindHolder, but it did not work...

How can I fix this issue?
https://github.com/kitomiyu/practice-hospitalList/issues/5

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TaskItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mItems != null) {
        TodoItem current = mItems.get(position);
        holder.itemName.setText(current.getText());
        holder.itemCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }
}

// provide a reference to the views for each data
class TaskItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final TextView itemName;
    private final CheckBox itemCheckBox;

    TaskItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
        itemCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskCheck);

        itemCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        TodoItem current = mItems.get(adapterPosition);
        TextPaint paint = itemName.getPaint();

        if (itemCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            // change color
            itemName.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            // add strikethrough
            paint.setFlags(itemName.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            // when item is checked, add the item as delete target
            mDeleteItems.add(current);
            mClickListener.onItemClick(mDeleteItems);
        } else {
            mDeleteItems.remove(current);
            itemName.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            paint.setFlags(itemName.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            paint.setAntiAlias(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting strikethru in both condition of Your `if else`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! 
yes, I added strikethru in 'else' as well because I wanted to remove it when checkbox is unchecked. 
This time I want to also remove strikethru when item of recyclerView is updated...i tried several ways, but did not work...